# Stop server in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a client server application in eclipse where the client and server connect through port 4444 to send numbers to eachother. However I am getting this error message

```
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Does this mean that the port is in use? Can anyone advise me on how to fix this error?

Comment: check port 4444 it may be unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one `ServerSocket` can bind a `SocketAddress` (IP address and port number). 
Possible reasons why the address is already bound:

- Another application on your system currently uses this port (in this case: pick another port)
- You may still have a running instance of your application in the background (in this case: terminate it in the console view in Eclipse)
- You attempted to bind the SocketAddress twice (in this case: fix your program).

Answer (score 0):

I believe port 4444 is blocked on some routers by default. Running the command netstat -a in cmd should give you a list of all ports in use. Try using a different port if possible.